# Get layers by class (Vector) then refresh does not work using Openlayer 2.14

Tags: javascript, openlayers

First, I get all the Vector layer then evaluate if it's visible and get its name. Then I want to remove all the filter on that layer then refresh.

Here's the snippet of the code:

```
var mLayers = map.getLayersByClass("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector");
for(var a = 0; a < mLayers.length; a++ ){
    if(mLayers[a].getVisibility()){     
        var layerName = mLayers[a].name;
        var vlayer = map.getLayersByName(layerName);
        //console.log(vlayer);
        vlayer.filter = null;
        vlayer.refresh({
            force: true
        });         
    }
};
```

It throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: vlayer.refresh is not a function

I noticed that if I used the assigned variable of the vector layer, refresh works.

For example:

```
var vector_bldg =new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Buildings", {
...
}
```

Then

```
vector_bldg .filter = null;
vector_bldg .refresh({
    force: true
});
```

Comment: you should seriously consider upgrading.  OL2 is very outdated.  nowadays, 4.2 is where the fun is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon checking the console the reason that the layer does not have the function to refresh is that it cannot access the variable. 
To solve this, instead of using:

```
var mLayers = map.getLayersByClass("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector");
for(var a = 0; a < mLayers.length; a++ ){
    if(mLayers[a].getVisibility()){     
        var layerName = mLayers[a].name;
        var vlayer = map.getLayersByName(layerName);
        //console.log(vlayer);
        vlayer.filter = null;
        vlayer.refresh({
            force: true
        });         
    }
};
```

Just change the variable to this:
[image]

```
var mLayers = map.getLayersByClass("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector");
    for(var a = 0; a < mLayers.length; a++ ){
        if(mLayers[a].getVisibility()){     
            var layerName = mLayers[a].name;
            var vlayer = map.getLayersByName(layerName);
            //console.log(vlayer);
            vlayer[0].filter = null;
            vlayer[0].refresh({
                force: true
            });         
        }
    };
```